# i have this assignment on java i am not sure if i am doing this right

Tags: java

Foo Corporation needs a program to calculate how much to pay their hourly employees.

The US Department of Labor requires that employees get paid time and a half for any hours over 40 that they work in a single week.

For example, if an employee works 45 hours, they get 5 hours of overtime, at 1.5 times their base pay.

The State of Massachusetts requires that hourly employees be paid at least $8.00 an hour.

Foo Corp requires that an employee not work more than 60 hours in a week.

An employee gets paid (hours worked) × (base pay), for each hour up to 40 hours. For every hour over 40, they get overtime = (base pay) × 1.5. The base pay must not be less than the minimum wage ($8.00 an hour). If it is, print an error. If the number of hours is greater than 60, print an error message.

Create a new class called FooCorporation.

Write a method that takes the base pay and hours worked as parameters, and prints the total pay or an error. Write a main method that calls this method for each of these employees:

Base Pay Hours Worked Employee 1 $7.50 35 Employee 2 $8.20 47 Employee 3 $10.00 73

You have to read base pay and hours from a text file in this format.

```
Employee, basePay, hours
1, 8, 40,
2, 9, 33,
3, 10, 70
```

Here is my code:

```
package foocorporation;

public class FooCorporation {
    double minimumWage = 8.0;
    int maxHours = 60;
    float x;
    int y;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        salaryCalculation(x,y, minimumWage, maxHours);
        salaryCalculation(x,y, minimumWage, maxHours);
        salaryCalculation(x,y, minimumWage, maxHours);

   }
     public static void salaryCalculation
    (double basePay, int hoursWorked, double minimumWage, int maxHours){
        double totalSalary = 0;
        if ((basePay < minimumWage) || (hoursWorked > maxHours)){
            System.out.println("Error!");
        }
        else {  
            if (hoursWorked > 40){
                totalSalary = basePay * 40 + 1.5*basePay*(hoursWorked - 40);
            }
            else {
                totalSalary = basePay * hoursWorked;
            }
            System.out.println("Your total salary is " + totalSalary);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you calling salaryCalculation method thrice?

Comment: From the code, i see you are passing `null` as the first 2 arguments into `salaryCalculation`.

Comment: Here you can make minimumWage and maxHours as final and no need to pass it as parameters.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "I'm not sure if I am doing this right" is not a valid question for SO, especially without any further comments on what may be going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at this

**UPDATE**
 if you want to take the input from the user as you asked later

```
public class FooCorporation {
    static final double minimumWage = 8.0; // static means that can be accessed without creating an object of the class and instantiating it
    static final int maxHours = 60; // final means constant = cannot be changed after declared
    static double basePay=0; // initialize them to zero, at least you know your program won't throw null pointer exception if forgot to set their 
                             //values before invoking the method
    static int hoursWorked=0;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i=1; i<=3; i++, System.out.println()){
           System.out.println("For Employee Number: " + i);
           System.out.println("Enter Base Pay:");
           basePay = in.nextDouble();
           System.out.println("Enter Hours Worked:");
           hoursWorked = in.nextInt();
           salaryCalculation(); 
       }
   }
     public static void salaryCalculation(){
        double totalSalary = 0;
        if ((basePay < minimumWage) || (hoursWorked > maxHours)){
            System.out.println("Error!");
        }
        else {   

        if (hoursWorked > 40){
                    totalSalary = basePay * 40 + 1.5*basePay*(hoursWorked - 40);
                }
                else {
                    totalSalary = basePay * hoursWorked;
                }
                System.out.println("Your total salary is " + totalSalary);
            }
        }

    }
```

result will be for your inputs for example:

```
For Employee Number: 1
Enter Base Pay:
7.5
Enter Hours Worked:
35
Error!

For Employee Number: 2
Enter Base Pay:
8.2
Enter Hours Worked:
47
Your total salary is 414.1

For Employee Number: 3
Enter Base Pay:
10
Enter Hours Worked:
37
Your total salary is 370.0
```

Comment: what if i had to take a text file as an input in order to get the salary of the employes?in this same code

Comment: what if the code has to read base pay and hours from a text file in this format.

Employee, basePay, hours
1, 8, 40,
2, 9, 33,
3, 10, 70
how would it be done?

Answer (score -1):

```
package foocorporation;

public class Foocorporation {
    final static double minimumWage = 8.0;
    final static int maxHours = 60;   
public static void main(String[] args) {
    float x;
    int y;
    x=7.5f;
    y=35;
    salaryCalculation(x,y);
    x=8.2f;
    y=47;
    salaryCalculation(x,y);
    x=10.0f;
    y=73;
    salaryCalculation(x,y);
   }
public static void salaryCalculation(double basePay, int hoursWorked){
    double totalSalary = 0;
    if ((basePay < minimumWage) || (hoursWorked > maxHours)){
    System.out.println("Error!");
}
    else {  
        if (hoursWorked > 40){
        totalSalary = basePay * 40 + 1.5*basePay*(hoursWorked - 40);
        }
        else {
        totalSalary = basePay * hoursWorked;
        }
        System.out.println("Your total salary is " + totalSalary);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Check it now. Its running.

Comment: i need to take input from the user.